# Umbraco 5 Localize text in Surface Controller

Tags: localization, umbraco

I've created a newsletter subscription form in Umbraco 5 using a Surface Controller. The controller renders a form with the input fields for the user. When I translate text in the view all works fine. I can use:

```
Umbraco.GetDictionaryItem("newslettertitle")
```

Or

```
@("newslettertitle".Localize())
```

When I handle the form submit I need to send a localized email. But localizing text doesn't work:
example:

```
            var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(settings.Smtp.From);
        mail.To.Add(aSubscriber.Email);
        mail.Subject = "newslettersucces".Localize();
```

The subject of the mail = (Umbraco.Cms.Web.newslettersucces). No localization. The same happens when I use GetDictionaryItem("newslettersuccess"). Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can push an Umbraco Helper in the view where you need Umbraco.GetDictionaryItem.
Created a BaseSurfaceController like:

```
public class BaseSurfaceController : SurfaceController    {
    public UmbracoHelper Umbraco{
        get {
           IRenderModelFactory modelFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRenderModelFactory>();
            return new UmbracoHelper(this.ControllerContext, this.RoutableRequestContext, modelFactory);
        }
    }
}
```

And also a base ViewModel:

```
    public class BaseViewModel
    {
        public UmbracoHelper Umbraco { get; set; }
    }
```

Example:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult ContactForm()

    {
        var model = new ContactViewModel();
        model.Umbraco = this.Umbraco;

        return PartialView(model);

    }
```

Source: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/29601-MVC-form-localization-ViewModel-plus-Umbraco-DictionaryItem

Comment: I think you didn't read the question right. Please read again. It's not about getting access to the Umbraco Helper class. Using translation like GetDictionaryItem or .Localize() doesn't work in the controller, only in the view.  Also your answer is a copy of a post of mine I put on the umbraco forum

Comment: Ok, sorry. I didn't even checked the owner names. I made it work actually, but only on the controller class Init function. I've not tested yet on the post form handle function of the same controller class. I will then have soon the same issue as your, needing to send a localized mail as well. I felt also in  an other issue related to my models properties attributes localization: [Display(Name="", [Required(ErrorMessage="", etc ... I can't get them issued by Umbraco dictionary... How did you manage that point ? Thanks

Comment: Ok that's fine. I don't think it's possible to use the Umbraco helper directly on your model attributes since it depends on a service or http request. My guess is that you'll have to resort to normal resource files or use the Umbraco localization framework (using the LocalizationEntries.xml file). see: http://kuhnel.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/an-101-on-the-localization-framework-in-umbraco-5/
For now I resorted to translating directly in my view